# CSS - Break only long words in html email in outlook 2010

Tags: css, outlook, css-tables, word-wrap, word-break

I have the following CSS for word break for use in an html email:

```
body {
        background-color: #F2F4F6;
        color: #74787E;
        height: 100%;
        hyphens: auto;
        line-height: 1.4;
        margin: 0;
        -moz-hyphens: auto;
        -ms-word-break: break-word; 
        width: 100% !important;
        -webkit-hyphens: auto;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
        word-break: break-all; 
        word-break: break-word;
    }
```

In Microsoft Outlook, normal words inside a table cell are split to a new line if it hits the edge of the cell instead of wrapping the entire word to a new line. The above CSS is fine for long hyperlinks but normal words that can fit on a new line are also getting split.

e.g

```
|                           |
|a-very-long-word-should-wra|
|p-like-this                |
|                           |
|words that can fit on      |
|another line should wrap   |
|like this                  |
|                           |
|The above css style is curr|
|ently doing this           |
```

How can I ensure only long words are wrapped but words that can fit on a new line move to a new line instead of getting split like in the last example above?

Comment: You should just be able to set `word-wrap: normal;`, no?

Comment: @1000Nettles please read my updated post. I need long words to wrap but normal words should not be cut off.